# imagemagick iOS - black border on animated gif

Tags: ios, objective-c, imagemagick, animated-gif

I'm creating a gif as below but I always end up with a black line on one or more of the edges as the attached image shows. How can I avoid this please?

```
//Create gif
        MagickWand *mw = NewMagickWand();
        MagickSetFormat(mw, "gif");

        for(int i = 0; i < [self.finalImageArray count]; i++)
        {
            float interval = (100/8);
            MagickWand *localWand = NewMagickWand();

            UIImage *image = [self.finalImageArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

            MagickReadImageBlob(localWand, [dataObj bytes], [dataObj length]);
            MagickThumbnailImage(localWand, 320, 320);
            MagickSetImageDelay(localWand, interval);
            MagickAddImage(mw, localWand);
            DestroyMagickWand(localWand);
        }

        size_t my_size;
        unsigned char * my_image = MagickGetImagesBlob(mw, &my_size);

        NSData *gifData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:my_image length:my_size];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the creation of the gif, the black line is created earlier when I scale the image